# how to integrate a facebook api

Tags: java, android, facebook

I have created an app and I have integrated it with Facebook.

The problem is there is a class file named Example in Facebook package and it is associated with the xml file named fb but the data are not retrieved from the fb.xml it shows errors as

```
setContentView(R.layout.fb);
            mLoginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login);
            mText = (TextView) Example.this.findViewById(R.id.txt);
//          mRequestButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.requestButton);
            mPostButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.postButton);
            mDeleteButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deletePostButton);
```

Any idea how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking if the buttons equals null. If so, they could not be found in the xml. That means that your xml contain errors. What is the error log?